# iOS App crashes on WLAN disconnect

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8, wifi

I am facing a strange problem with my iOS app.
It is written in Objective-C and i use iOS 8.3 on my testdevice (iPhone 4s).
The app uses push notifications.

When I lock my iPhone, I sometimes get the following issue: 
Before unlocking the device again, the wlan status symbol in the status bar disappears and when I finally unlock it, the app freezes and I have to restart it (-> The WLAN sign returns and the app works without any problems)

Comment: How exactly are you able to tell WLAN has anything to do with your app crashing ? Grab the crash report, symbolicate it and you should see the real reason, right now you might as well say it crashes because of the  screen brightness changes.

Comment: But most of the time, the app doesn't crash, when it's connected to X-Code...